# Como pegar todos os valores de um select e executar em uma procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como pegar todos os valores de um select e jogar em uma procedure para dar um insert sem que execute um valor por vez?

Tenho o seguinte codigo sql:

```
   --drop table #tabelaEntSaida;

   --drop table #tabelaEntSaida;

 CREATE TABLE #tabelaEntSaida (
  EmpCod varchar (30),
  FiscalNFDataEmissao datetime,
  FiscalNFDataSaiEnt datetime,
  FiscalNFEspec varchar(30), 
  NatOperacao varchar(30),
  FiscalNFSerie varchar(5), 
  FiscalNFnum varchar(50), 
  PaisSigla varchar(3), 
  UfSigla varchar(2), 
  EntCod varchar(30), 
  UsuCod varchar(30)
)

DECLARE 
@EmpCod varchar(30), 
@FiscalNFDataEmissao datetime,
@FiscalNFDataSaiEnt datetime,
@FiscalNFEspec varchar(30), 
@NatOperacao varchar(50),
@FiscalNFSerie varchar(5), 
@FiscalNFnum varchar(50), 
@PaisSigla varchar(3), 
@UfSigla varchar(2), 
@EntCod varchar(30), 
@USUARIO varchar(30),
@MSG varchar(50),
@Contador varchar(30)

set @MSG = ''


 DECLARE cursor_gera_entrada_saida CURSOR FOR

 SELECT DISTINCT
    NF.EmpCod, 
    NF.FiscalNFDataEmis,
    NF.FiscalNFDataSaiEnt, 
    NF.FiscalNFEspec, 
    ITNF.NatOpCodEstr,
    NF.FiscalNFSerie, 
    NF.FiscalNFnum, 
    NF.PaisSigla, 
    NF.UfSigla, 
    NF.EntCod,
    NF.UsuCod
FROM 
FISCAL_NF NF
LEFT JOIN FISCAL_ITEM_NF ITNF ON ITNF.FiscalNFChv = NF.FiscalNFChv
WHERE NF.FiscalNFEspec = 'NFC-E' and NF.EmpCod = '01.01'


 OPEN cursor_gera_entrada_saida


 FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_gera_entrada_saida INTO 

@EmpCod, 
@FiscalNFDataEmissao,
@FiscalNFDataSaiEnt,
@FiscalNFEspec, 
@NatOperacao,
@FiscalNFSerie, 
@FiscalNFNum, 
@PaisSigla, 
@UfSigla, 
@EntCod, 
@USUARIO


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

/* inserindo na tabela temporaria */
INSERT INTO #tabelaEntSaida (
  EmpCod,
  FiscalNFDataEmissao,
  FiscalNFDataSaiEnt,
  FiscalNFEspec, 
  NatOperacao,
  FiscalNFSerie, 
  FiscalNFnum, 
  PaisSigla, 
  UfSigla, 
  EntCod, 
  UsuCod
) values (
    @EmpCod, 
    @FiscalNFDataEmissao, 
    @FiscalNFDataSaiEnt,
    @FiscalNFEspec, 
    @NatOperacao,
    @FiscalNFSerie, 
    @FiscalNFNum, 
    @PaisSigla, 
    @UfSigla, 
    @EntCod, 
    @USUARIO
)

/* insere na proceure */
EXECUTE GERA_LIVRO_ENT_bkp 
    @EmpCod,
    @FiscalNFDataEmissao,
    @FiscalNFDataSaiEnt,
    @NatOperacao,
    @FiscalNFEspec,
    @FiscalNFSerie,
    @FiscalNFNum,
    @FiscalNFNum,
    @UfSigla,
    @PaisSigla,
    @EntCod,
    '',
    @USUARIO,
    @MSG

-- Lendo a próxima linha
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_gera_entrada_saida INTO 
    @EmpCod, 
    @FiscalNFDataEmissao,
    @FiscalNFDataSaiEnt,
    @FiscalNFEspec, 
    @NatOperacao,
    @FiscalNFSerie, 
    @FiscalNFnum, 
    @PaisSigla, 
    @UfSigla, 
    @EntCod, 
    @USUARIO
  END

 select * from #tabelaEntSaida;

 drop table #tabelaEntSaida;

 -- Fechando Cursor para leitura
CLOSE cursor_gera_entrada_saida

-- Desalocando o cursor
DEALLOCATE cursor_gera_entrada_saida
```

Imagem do select retornado. Quero que jogue todos estes valores na procedure:
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Até um tempo atrás eu enviava vários registros para uma procedure da seguinte forma: convertendo o resultado do `select` para XML, a procedure esperava como parâmetro um `VARCHAR(7999)` e era utilizado o `OPENXML` para ler o XML e inserir os registros em uma tabela temporária. Só que eu descobri uma forma mais elegante de fazer isso: usando [Table-Valued Parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2014)

Pegando seu código de exemplo, criei a tabela `FISCAL_NF_BKP` para inserir todos os registros recebidos na procedure.

1. Definir um Type como Tabela e criar a procedure recebendo o type criado como parâmetro.

```sql
CREATE TYPE RegistrosNotaFiscal 
      AS TABLE
         (EmpCod VARCHAR (30),
         FiscalNFDataEmissao DATETIME,
         FiscalNFDataSaiEnt DATETIME,
         FiscalNFEspec VARCHAR(30), 
         NatOperacao VARCHAR(30),
         FiscalNFSerie VARCHAR(5), 
         FiscalNFnum VARCHAR(50), 
         PaisSigla VARCHAR(3), 
         UfSigla VARCHAR(2), 
         EntCod VARCHAR(30), 
         UsuCod VARCHAR(30))
   GO
```

[image: Criando um tipo tabela]

```sql
     CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GERA_LIVRO_ENT_bkp (@EntradaSaida RegistrosNotaFiscal READONLY)

    AS

          SET NOCOUNT ON

         -- CONTEÚDO DA SUA PROCEDURE ...

         INSERT INTO FISCAL_NF_BKP
         SELECT * FROM @EntradaSaida
    GO
```

[image: procedure]

2. Depois disso, você pode declarar uma variável do tipo tabela criado
   anteriormente, inserir registros e chamar a procedure.

```sql
    DECLARE @TabelaEntradaSaida AS RegistrosNotaFiscal

    INSERT INTO @TabelaEntradaSaida
    SELECT DISTINCT
        NF.EmpCod, 
        NF.FiscalNFDataEmissao,
        NF.FiscalNFDataSaiEnt, 
        NF.FiscalNFEspec, 
        ITNF.NatOpCodEstr,
        NF.FiscalNFSerie, 
        NF.FiscalNFnum, 
        NF.PaisSigla, 
        NF.UfSigla, 
        NF.EntCod,
        NF.UsuCod 
    FROM FISCAL_NF NF
    LEFT JOIN FISCAL_ITEM_NF ITNF ON ITNF.FiscalNFChv = NF.FiscalNFChv
    WHERE NF.FiscalNFEspec = 'NFC-E' and NF.EmpCod = '01.01'


    SELECT * FROM @TabelaEntradaSaida


    EXEC GERA_LIVRO_ENT_bkp @TabelaEntradaSaida;
```

[image: Tabela FISCAL_NF_BKP antes de executar a procedure]

[image: Tabela FISCAL_NF_BKP DEPOIS de executar a procedure]

Se você for fazer isso em C# você pode ver nesta [referência](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters).

Comment: Não deu muito certo. Ele não gravou os valores. Como que eu faço para poder listar nas variáveis correspondentes da procedure?   

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GERA_LIVRO_ENT_bkp (@EntradaSaida RegistrosNotaFiscal1 READONLY)
   AS
         SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE

      @EMPCOD VARCHAR(20),     etc

Comment: Mas a procedure recebeu todos os registros na variável @EntradaSaida!? O que não gravou foram os registros da variável @EntradaSaida em outra tabela que você está tentando fazer o `insert` dentro da procedure, é isso?? Para pegar todos os registros e ir jogando em variáveis dentro da procedure, você teria que fazer um `while` ou um `cursos`, que é o que você já estava fazendo. Mas aí não faz sentido você passar todos os registros por parâmetro e depois fazer um `loop`.

Comment: Isso mesmo, Raquel. TVP é a melhor forma de passar tabela como parâmetro. Já ganhou +1logo no parágrafo inicial.